# Prove If lim inf sn = lim sup sn, then lim sn is defined and lim sn = lim inf sn = lim sup sn

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

I need a proof verification or some pointers.

The definition from the book says:

1. $\limsup s_n = \lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \sup \{s_n : n > N\}$
2. $\liminf s_n = \lim\limits_{N\to\infty} \sup \{s_n : n > N\}$.

Case 1. lim inf {$s_n$} = lim sup {$s_n$} = positive infinity

Proof: Let M > 0. Then there exists some n such that n > N implies $s_n$ > M. The question is I'm only given:
lim inf {$s_n$} = lim sup {$s_n$}. How do I construct this $s_n$ so that lim inf {$s_n$}= lim $s_n$ = lim sup {$s_n$}.
Can I just apply the squeeze theorem here? Then lim sn is defined and lim sn = lim inf sn = lim sup sn by squeeze theorem?. Help?

Comment: *there exists some n such that n > N implies lim inf {$s_n$} = lim sup {$s_n$}*: It's not clear what you're trying to say here, but what you *have* said is wrong.  What is your definition of a liminf or limsup?

Comment: This comes from assumption. The line If lim inf sn = lim sup sn, then lim sn is defined and lim sn = lim inf sn = lim sup sn.

I'm supposing lim inf sn = lim sup sn. Then because of infinite limits definition: There exists an N s.t. n > N implies $s_n$ > M.

Comment: Okay... so it looks like what you were *trying* to say then was: *Then there exists some $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $s_n > M$*, rather than what you actually said about $N$.

Comment: I still need to get lim inf {$s_n$}= lim $s_n$ = lim sup {$s_n$}... I'm not sure how "Then there exists some $N$ such that n>$N$ implies $s_n$ > $M$" helps me...

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to prove, if you want to use the definition of a limit directly (at least in the $+\infty$ case) is that

> For any $M>0$: there is an $N$ such that for any $n > N$, $s_n > M$

From your knowledge of the liminf, you know that

> For any $M >0$: there is an $N$ such that $\inf \{s_n:n>N\} > M$

Why does this second statement imply the first?

---

For $\pm \infty$, you will need only the liminf or the limsup.  For finite limits, however, you will need both.

The conclusion we want to reach is

> For any $\epsilon > 0$: there is an $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $|s_n - L| < \epsilon$.

Using the liminf and limsup, we have the statements:

> For any $\epsilon > 0$: there is an $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $\inf \{s_n : n>N\} > L - \epsilon$
>
> For any $\epsilon > 0$: there is an $N$ such that $n > N$ implies $\sup \{s_n : n > N\} < L + \epsilon$

How do these two statements let you deduce the first?

---

You could also use the squeeze theorem if you note that
$$
\inf \{s_n: n \geq N\} \leq s_N \leq \sup\{s_n: n \geq N\}
$$
and take the limit as $N \to \infty$.

Comment: Um, I'm not sure why the second actually implies the first statement. Is it an if and only if statement?

Comment: I should have used the inf there, my mistake.

Comment: How do these two statements let you deduce the first? I'm not sure how.

Comment: For any M>0: there is an N such that for any n>$N$, $s_n$>$M$
From your knowledge of the lim inf, you know that :

For any $M$>0: there is an $N$ such that inf{$s_n$:n>$N$}>$M$.

is there a definition that $s_n$ $\geq$ inf{sn:n>N}>M

Comment: If you don't see why, then you need to start unpacking the definitions.  What is the infimum of a set? What is the supremum? It might help to try a proof by contradiction: if the first statement (limit definition) *failed* to hold, could the next two statements both hold?  Why not?

Comment: If you know the definition of the infimum, then it should be obvious to you that
$$
s_k \geq \inf \{s_n:n>N\}
$$
if $k > N$.